# extend property of base interface

Tags: typescript

I have:

```
interface A {
  x: {
    f1(s: string): string;
  };
}

interface B extends A {

}
```

I want to extend A.x to include f2 in B (without having to redeclare f1). Something like:

```
interface B extends A {
  x: {
    f2(s: string): string;
  };
}
```

is this possible? any references/docs around this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use generics, something like:

```
interface X1 {
    f1(s: string): string;
}

interface X2 {
    f2(s: string): string;
}

interface A<T> {
  x: T
}

interface A1 extends A<X1> {}

interface A2 extends A<X2> {}
```

Comment: i want x in B to have both f1 & f2. does this solution do that?

Comment: @Srinivas if you change my code to `interface X2 extends X1` then yes.